# Delete interface open camera on Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, camera

I really need help here. I have project which call MyHeartRate, I downloaded the source code of heart rate project at Github. So I try to run that source code and there is no error. In the interface layout, it display the "camera". Example, when you open your camera then you will see the screen focus on what area that you want to take the picture. So my problem is, I want to remove that "camera" in my layout. I need to know which code need to be delete so then the "camera" not in my layout.

here's my code

### xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/layout">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/top"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="@string/default_text"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
    </TextView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <com.jwetherell.heart_rate_monitor.HeartbeatView android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </com.jwetherell.heart_rate_monitor.HeartbeatView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<SurfaceView android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
</SurfaceView>
```

### java file(HeartRateMonitor)

```
public class HeartRateMonitor extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "HeartRateMonitor";
private static final AtomicBoolean processing = new AtomicBoolean(false);

private static SurfaceView preview = null;
private static SurfaceHolder previewHolder = null;
private static Camera camera = null;
private static View image = null;
private static TextView text = null;

private static WakeLock wakeLock = null;

private static int averageIndex = 0;
private static final int averageArraySize = 4;
private static final int[] averageArray = new int[averageArraySize];

public static enum TYPE {
    GREEN, RED
};

private static TYPE currentType = TYPE.GREEN;

public static TYPE getCurrent() {
    return currentType;
}

private static int beatsIndex = 0;
private static final int beatsArraySize = 3;
private static final int[] beatsArray = new int[beatsArraySize];
private static double beats = 0;
private static long startTime = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
    previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
    previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
    previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    image = findViewById(R.id.image);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "DoNotDimScreen");
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    wakeLock.acquire();

    camera = Camera.open();

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    wakeLock.release();

    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}

private static PreviewCallback previewCallback = new PreviewCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
        if (data == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        Camera.Size size = cam.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
        if (size == null) throw new NullPointerException();

        if (!processing.compareAndSet(false, true)) return;

        int width = size.width;
        int height = size.height;

        int imgAvg = ImageProcessing.decodeYUV420SPtoRedAvg(data.clone(), height, width);
        // Log.i(TAG, "imgAvg="+imgAvg);
        if (imgAvg == 0 || imgAvg == 255) {
            processing.set(false);
            return;
        }

        int averageArrayAvg = 0;
        int averageArrayCnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < averageArray.length; i++) {
            if (averageArray[i] > 0) {
                averageArrayAvg += averageArray[i];
                averageArrayCnt++;
            }
        }

        int rollingAverage = (averageArrayCnt > 0) ? (averageArrayAvg / averageArrayCnt) : 0;
        TYPE newType = currentType;
        if (imgAvg < rollingAverage) {
            newType = TYPE.RED;
            if (newType != currentType) {
                beats++;
                // Log.d(TAG, "BEAT!! beats="+beats);
            }
        } else if (imgAvg > rollingAverage) {
            newType = TYPE.GREEN;
        }

        if (averageIndex == averageArraySize) averageIndex = 0;
        averageArray[averageIndex] = imgAvg;
        averageIndex++;

        // Transitioned from one state to another to the same
        if (newType != currentType) {
            currentType = newType;
            image.postInvalidate();
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double totalTimeInSecs = (endTime - startTime) / 1000d;
        if (totalTimeInSecs >= 10) {
            double bps = (beats / totalTimeInSecs);
            int dpm = (int) (bps * 60d);
            if (dpm < 30 || dpm > 180) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                beats = 0;
                processing.set(false);
                return;
            }

            // Log.d(TAG,
            // "totalTimeInSecs="+totalTimeInSecs+" beats="+beats);

            if (beatsIndex == beatsArraySize) beatsIndex = 0;
            beatsArray[beatsIndex] = dpm;
            beatsIndex++;

            int beatsArrayAvg = 0;
            int beatsArrayCnt = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < beatsArray.length; i++) {
                if (beatsArray[i] > 0) {
                    beatsArrayAvg += beatsArray[i];
                    beatsArrayCnt++;
                }
            }
            int beatsAvg = (beatsArrayAvg / beatsArrayCnt);
            text.setText(String.valueOf(beatsAvg));
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            beats = 0;
        }
        processing.set(false);
    }
};

private static SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
            camera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback", "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        Camera.Size size = getSmallestPreviewSize(width, height, parameters);
        if (size != null) {
            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
            Log.d(TAG, "Using width=" + size.width + " height=" + size.height);
        }
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

   @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Ignore
    }
};

private static Camera.Size getSmallestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result = null;

    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            } else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                if (newArea < resultArea) result = size;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

tq,
faizal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. just comment this code

```
//preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
//previewHolder = preview.getHolder();
//previewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
//previewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

done.